# what can cause this exception? io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Connection is not active now, current status: CLOSED

Tags: vert.x

i had built a http server by vertx-web, and it has working well for several days.

but today, when i make some http request, there sometimes throw this exception: "io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Connection is not active now, current status: CLOSED".

what make me confused is that not every http request will throw this exception, and for the same http uri, if i change the request params, this exception may happen, but not every time.

i wanne know why and thanks for you answer.

Comment: It might be helpful to share the relevant code along with steps to reproduce the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.